# Angular 2 + Bootstrap not working with iPhone 6 Safari

Tags: angular

I ran into an Angular2 problem and am hoping you may be able to help.

I am creating a site http://www.devonlewis.us

It works great on Chrome & Mozilla for my browser, but when I look at it on my iPhone the media queries don't seem work. It's weird because it works fine on my browser when I resize the screen and it even looks fine on online mobile phone simulators like this one: http://mobiletest.me/

I also noticed it doesn't function properly on Safari, but I am more concerned about the mobile phone issue. I attempted to use polyfills but they didn't help, they only allowed the page to load in safari, however the translates are still being ignored.

Any ideas would be great!

Regards,

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: No I haven't yet. I think I might just rebuild with Angular JS, I heard that Angular2 isn't compatible yet. Hopefully someone on here can provide a solution soon enough.